# NSDateFormatter with default time zone gives different date than NSDate description method

Tags: iphone, date, formatting, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Date: %@ formatted: %@", date, dateString);
[_dateFormatter release];
```

Gives me wrong date formatted:

**Date: 2013-01-31 18:00:00 +0000 formatted: 31-01-13 19:00 (from timestamp: 1359655200.000000)**

Online conversion tool: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm indicates that 1st date is correct: 2013-01-31 18:00:00 +0000.

Why NSDateFormatter produces different date that NSLog? Shouldn't `[NSDate description]` use defaultTimeZone when printing to console? I get the same error with `[_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]`; and `[_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]`;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is correct behavior, because:

1. `[NSDate description]` uses UTC, not the local time zone (that's why there's a `+0000` in the description).
2. Your `NSDateFormatter` is using the local time zone.
3. You are in Denmark, where the local time zone is Central European Time, which is currently UTC plus one hour.

The only way these will match up is if you tell `NSDateFormatter` to use UTC. That might not be what you want, though.

Comment: [_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]]; solved it.

Comment: Just FTI, it's generally better to use `timeZoneWithName:` instead of `timeZoneWithAbbreviation:`. For UTC it doesn't matter, but in most cases the name is the better choice.

Comment: The reason why is some abbreviations are the same, such as EST is in Australia and the US.

Comment: @TomHarrington why?

Comment: Abbreviations are not unique, and may be used by more than one time zone. Names are unique.

Answer (score -1):

It is the timezone problem as you discovered. Default time zone takes the system timezone. Say, if you are in GMT+1, you are supposed to get 19-00. The converter you have used gives you GMT time.

If you want time specific timezone and you know the offset from GMT you can use the following,

```
    [_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:2*60*60]];//GMT+2.0
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: This is not right. I was always sure that it is other way around but I tried it anyway and ended up with even worse: 31-00-13 19:01

Comment: That is a terrible way to get a specific time zone. What happens when the time zone switches to (or from) summer time, as many time zones do? `NSTimeZone` provides much better ways to get a time zone reference that will remain accurate tomorrow, next week, six months from now, etc.

Comment: @TomHarrington, I agree the method doesn't take daylight savings into account. But it's possible to get the offset from GMT for the local time and use it in place of the constant I added in the example. Also to add more info to the discussion apple doc says, its not a good idea to use abbreviation as it is not standardised http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/timeZoneWithAbbreviation:

Comment: The problem isn't that you used a hard coded constant, it's that you use a fixed offset from GMT, period. Using any numeric offset from GMT is asking for trouble. Summer time might start or end while your app is running. And, time zone abbreviations may not be standard, but the time zone names **are**, and there's a `timeZoneWithName:` method that looks up a zone object by name.

Comment: @TomHarrington I agree. I just wanted to add some information to the discussion should be useful to someone.